# Function passed to onClick doesn't execute completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, dom-events, react-dom

I have a function that passed to `onClick` event but it doesn't execute the `setDisable()` function in the following block of code:

```
let [answerClicked, setAnswerClicked] = React.useState()
let [disable, setDisable] = React.useState(true)

const onNextChange = () =>{
    
    if(questionNumber < 9 && disable === false){
        setQuestionNumber((questionNumber) => questionNumber + 1)
        setAnswer((answer) => answer.concat(answerClicked))
    }
}

const getTargetHtml = e => {
    const {target:{outerText}} = e
    const answer = outerText
    answerClicked = {questionId, answer}
    setAnswerClicked(answerClicked)      
    setDisable(false)
}

return(
   <div className='friendeval'>
   <h2 className='friendeval__header'>Friend Evaluation</h2> 
   <div className='friendeval__question-count'>Question {friendEvalData[questionNumber].questionId}/10</div> 
    <div className='align'>
        <img className='friendeval__image'alt='' src={friendEvalData[questionNumber].image}/> 
    </div>
   <div className='friendeval__question'>{friendEvalData[questionNumber].question}</div>
   <div className="friendeval__buttons">
       {

        options.map(option => <button disabled={disable} onClick={getTargetHtml}>{option}</button>)
           
       }
   </div>
   <div className="friendeval__nav">
       <button onClick={onNextChange}>Next</button>
   </div>
</div>
)
```

Everything works but the `setDisable` function I'm trying to get the `disable` variable to toggle to `false` anytime I click on the buttons which will allow me to use the `onNextChange` handler

Comment: did this line really runs? `options.map(option => <button disabled={disable} onClick={(getTargetHtml)}>{option}</button>)`. You passed the onClick function incorrectly. One morething, why you know the `setDisable()` did not invoke ?

Comment: Yes it does, changed the initial post to the correct format I was trying to add multiple function inside the **onClick** event that's why i added the brackets. I know the set state does not invoke because i have **onNextChange** handler that only works when the conditions are meet `const onNextChange = () =>{if(questionNumber < 9 && disable === false){setQuestionNumber((questionNumber) => questionNumber + 1)`

Comment: Hm... Please to make sure the click handler runs ? I tried to reproduce your code, when the button is disabled, the oncClick handler does not run when you clicked.

Comment: Thank you for feedback I'm really grateful I've updated the question to have more details about the code so you can have a closer look at it again ... the `onClick` handler runs      ` answerClicked = {questionId, answer} ` and `setAnswerClicked(answerClicked)` works i console logged it out but the `setDisable` does not switch to false which makes my `onNextChange` handler inactive

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getTargetHtml = e => {
    //your code
}
```

```
<button  onClick={getTargetHtml} />
```

This should solve the bug.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but it doesn't solve the problem I've edited the question with the corrections too